# How to get list of active users in tomcat

Tags: java

How do I get the list of active users logged in using `session`.

I have tried `session.getOpenSessions()` but the value is `null`.

This one I need it for my web socket chat program...

Pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JMX (Java Managemnet eXtension) like this :

```
jmxObjectName:    Catalina:host=localhost,path=/,type=Manager
jmxAttributeName: activeSessions
```

You can use jconsole to access this data. To get jmx running see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html

Answer (score 1):

To get a session list within tomcat

```
import javax.management.remote.*;
import org.apache.catalina.*;


MBeanServer mBeanServer = MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null).get(0);
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina", "type", "Server");
Server tomcatServer = (org.apache.catalina.Server) mBeanServer.getAttribute(name, "managedResource");
Service service = tomcatServer.findService("Catalina");
Engine engine = (Engine) service.getContainer();
Host host = (Host) engine.findChild(engine.getDefaultHost());
Context context = (Context) host.findChild("");
StandardManager manager = (StandardManager) context.getManager();
Session[] sessions=manager.findSessions();
```